# General solution to ODE

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, fourier-analysis, differential-equations

Considering the following ODE : find $f(x)$ such that 
$$\frac{\sigma^{2}}{2}\frac{d^2}{dx^2}f(x)+a(b-x)\frac{d}{dx}f(x)-(\rho+\lambda)f(x)=-\lambda g(x) $$
Where, $a,b,\rho,\lambda,\sigma\in(0,+\infty)$, and  $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are assumed to have enough "good properties" !

Using the Fourier transform, one specific solution could be found, but I am interested in finding a general solution. 
It would be great if some one could give me some ideas. Thanks for your time and consideration.

Comment: It's linear in $f$  

Comment: Hi Will, I am little confused by your comment, it would be great if you could clarify your comment for me 

Comment: The difference of two solutions of an inhomogeneous linear equation is a solution of the corresponding homogeneous equation.

Comment: Nameless, given the elementary nature of this question and your comments indicating lack of understanding of basic facts about linear ODEs, I suggest (a) reading a textbook on ODEs; (b) asking your teachers (if you are a student); (c) posting follow-up questions on other sites listed at the FAQ. Voting to close.

Answer (score 4):

Will + Victor noted the general solution is your particular solution plus the general solution of the corresponding homogeneous DE.  And, note, that this homogeneous DE does not depend on $g$.  According to Maple, the solution of that homogeneous DE is...
$$
f_\mathrm{homog} (x) = C_1 \mathrm{KummerM} \left(\frac{\rho + \lambda}{2 a},\frac{1}{2},\frac{a (b - x)^{2}}{\sigma^{2}}\right) +
C_2 \mathrm{KummerU} \left(\frac{\rho + \lambda}{2 a},\frac{1}{2},\frac{a (b - x)^{2}}{\sigma^{2}}\right)
$$

Comment: Dear Gerald I thank for your comment but it is really sorry to say the solution you gave makes nonsense for me. All I need are the techniques used to solve the problem. Thanks again

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confluent_hypergeometric_function